# FileZilla Issue?

Tags: windows-7, windows

am trying to register LiveZilla server but when it gets to creating the 'livezilla' folder using the wizard I get an error (550) access denied. any ideas. The 'htdocs' folder is not accessible for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions on the directory.  What are the exact permissions on the htdocs folder?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, certain folders are marked as protected by the OS. Try using another folder, or better yet - create a new folder, preferably in your user's document folder.

If htdocs is in your "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" folders it will automatically get protected status.